# How can i print number of times each alphabet occurs in the string?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

Well i was trying to write an code for isogram in python as my assignment so i got stuck here

I considered following things

1.All the words entered are in small
2. It only contains alphabets and no special characters or numbers

```
word =input("enter the word ")
list_of_alphabets = list(word)
no_of_alphabets = len(list_of_alphabets)
for i in range(no_of_alphabets):
  number = list_of_alphabets.count()
  print (number)
```

I got stuck here now i want the for loop to check whether each alphabet occurs once or not and print number of times each alphabet occurs. If not then it should print not an isogram , and print an isogram if it is. Also if there is some other way to this code i would also like that

**PS. Please don't suggest me the code from geeksforgeek as i have already seen it**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Corrections to your posted code.

*Changes to your code*

```
word = input("enter the word ")
#list_of_alphabets = list(word)               -- not needed
#no_of_alphabets = len(list_of_alphabets)     -- not needed
#for i in range(no_of_alphabets):             --  change to following
for letter in word:                          # loop through each letter in word
  number = word.count(letter)      
  if number > 1:
    print("Not a isogram")
    break
else:
    # Will enter here only if did not encounter break in above for loop
    print("Is a isogram")
```

*After cleaning up the above we have*

```
word = input("enter the word ")
for letter in word:
  number = word.count(letter)      
  if number > 1:
    print("Not a isogram")
    break
else:
    print("Is a isogram")
```

*Alternative Suggested by Daniel Hao*

Using Python [sets](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html)

```
word = input("enter the word ")
if len(word) == len(set(word)):
    print("Is a isogram")
else:
    print("Not a isogram")
```

Comment: Or even simpler - just use 'set' to check the len before and after
...

Comment: @DanielHao--another good option so added it as an alternative.

Comment: Cool.  Then it could be made as a simple function - `is_isogram(word)`  as one-line.  Thx.

Answer (score 4):

Just use `collections.Counter`:

```py
>>> c = Counter('gallahad')
>>> c
Counter({'a': 3, 'l': 2, 'g': 1, 'h': 1, 'd': 1})
```

If you need to check how many specific symbols are in your string, use `count` method:

```py
>>> 'gallahad'.count("a")
3
```

Answer (score 2):

as per@dukkee opinion. You can also try this

```
value ="gallahad"
print({i:value.count(i) for i in value})
```